# Package DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE - how to stop(kill) executing task

Tags: oracle11g, parallel-processing

We are using DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE in Oracle 11g R2 as following

scheduled job run a procedure which creates and runs parallel task using package DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE. Sometime scheduled job hangs and is needed to be restarted. And my question is how to properly kill executing parallel task?
Using DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.DROP_TASK or DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.STOP_TASK procedures do not help - I can see sessions of task processes (it creates the same amount of new processes as parameter parallel_level of DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK). The same with killing scheduled job (dbms_job.remove) and killing job session - task sessions still available.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself. I was concetrated on dbms_job package and related view dba_jobs_running. I found that dbms_job is depreciated package. Oracle (11g) use dbms_scheduler package when run parallel task's jobs. They are visible in dba_scheduler_running_jobs and can be stopped by dbms_scheduler.stop_job. This action also stops upper level job and all related sessions. Also parallel task get status **Crashed**.